# Admin login issue-Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2, admin-login

I am facing issue **"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page"** while trying to log-in into magento admin-panel.
I know there are many queries went on the same topic but none helped me out.
This is happening to me only in my staging site and that too happened when I created staging site using production.
Live site's URL is www.xyz.com
Staging site's URL is staging.xyz.com
There may be a case of cookie conflict but not sure. Helping hands are most welcome!
[image]

Comment: Go to db. Open `core_config_data` and set the cookie domain. Or may be you dont have the form key in that phtml file.

Comment: `Cookie Path: /`  and `Cookie Domain: .xyz.com`

Comment: @KingshukDeb I have formkey in the form. Your next solution do not helped. Same issue persists

Comment: @KingshukDeb If I clear browser cache, then it works fine OR if I access from firefox, it works fine. Is it that since I am accessing both staging and production in the same broswer, so cookie conflict happening?

Comment: Not sure. If previous solution doesnt work then try this. Go to `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien` file and scroll to line no. 97. Check if the code is commented out or not.

Comment: @KingshukDeb Thats a bad solution to check core file for this as this is already working fine in production and local env

Comment: I didnt ask you to change core file. I just asked you to check it.

Comment: @KingshukDeb Oh, I mistakken, I will check